# Redirect from Wordpress to Laravel if user logged into Laravel?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I have the following situation:

- an Apache server on a Linux machine
- a Wordpress site at domain.com
- a Laravel application at software.domain.com

If a user is logged into the Laravel application, and they visit the Wordpress site, they should be redirected back to the Laravel application.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I've been considering cookies, but in this case, the Laravel app would have to create a cookie, and the Wordpress site should be able to read it somehow.

Possibly some type of API call from Wordpress to Laravel could work, but I'm not sure how to set that up on the Wordpress side.

Perhaps an `.htaccess` solution is also possible, but I don't see how.

Comment: you can use js to read cookies on wp. there are some small limitation on "secure" cookies but you can have one insecure that just says loggedin=yes/no

Comment: Is the "logged in" a security requirement or something else? If it is security, you need to perform an API-like call. If it is a feature that you don't mind occasional mistakes (or attackers) then the cookie might be good enough. I would consider this, first. For the API, is it every possibly page on WordPress? If so, you can probably just hook into the `init` or similar action, make a simple GET request to your Laravel app,

Comment: @ChrisHaas It's not about security, it's simply that if a user is logged in (in Laravel) and they go back to the landing page (in Wordpress) they should be sent to Laravel immediately.

Comment: In that case, I would just look for the presence of a session cookie, that should be good enough for 99% of cases, and you might be able to do it in JS even. In your Laravel app, you'll have to set the cookie domain to be a bit wider. Here's a [Laravel 5 version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30407141/231316) that hopefully you can use or change for your version.

Comment: Like @LelioFaieta said, a simple boolean cookie would suffice. You'd set the cookie upon logging in and read this cookie on the Wordpress site. If the cookie is true, make a redirect. Unset the cookie on logging out in Laravel.

Comment: @BartKleinReesink How would I read the cookie from Wordpress? I developed the Laravel app, but I don't know anything about WP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, cookie would be the most suitable approach to achieve this. Since security is not really a concern, then it's even easier.

Once logged in from Laravel, you can [set a cookie](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses) which can identify if the user is logged in or not. If you're using Laravel's authentication scaffolding, you'll be doing this in your `authenticated()` function.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request)
{
    // cookie('name', 'value', $minutes, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly)
    return response('Logged in.')->cookie('logged_in', true, 120);
}
```

Make sure you've set your `.env` with `SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.com`, so that the cookie is at the top level of the domain rather than subdomain. If for any reason you need to set your `SESSION_DOMAIN` to the subdomain, you'll then need to pass the top-level domain into the parameter. Also remember to remove the cookie once the user logout. If you're using Laravel scaffolding, use the `loggedOut()` function.

Now you can have your WordPress read this cookie and do the redirect if the `logged_in` cookie is set. Alternatively, you could do the [redirection using Apache `.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19382292/3209381).

Comment: What if the user's session expires for some other reason (other than them logging out manually)? The cookie will continue to exist, no?

Comment: In that case, I suggest to set the same cookie expiration time as your session time, so it would sync.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) I want the bounty, but can not think of anything better, just create a WP must-use plugin, like `wp-content/mu-plugins/my-plugin.php` file (for handling the redirection).

Comment: I've already awarded the bounty, but I have a quick follow-up question: if the user checks the "remember me" option on login, then the session doesn't expire in 120 minutes (as in the default). How can I handle this when setting the cookie in order to keep it the same length as the session?

Comment: @svetipetar In your login controller, you can determine if the remember me is set (either from the request or [viaRemember()](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html#method_viaRemember)). Then you can set the cookie expiration to [forever](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.php#L88) (5 years I believe).

Comment: Thanks. I'm still having trouble actually checking the cookie from Wordpress. Any link for how to do that? I'v created the cookie on the top domain but I don't see how I can check it in Wordpress.

Comment: If I do var_dump($_COOKIE) from the Wordpress page, I see the cookie created in Laravel. But I don't know how to check it before the page loads.

Comment: I think you can do this in your theme's `function.php` or make a simple plugin like Top-Master said. You can `isset($_COOKIE['logged_in'])` and then do the redirection. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268138/using-wp-redirect-to-redirect-wordpress-pages